# Meteor game laggy when 7+ users on

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm making a multiplayer Jeopardy! clone in Meteor and am having problems with lag when 7 or so players are playing. For example, if a user clicks a button on the game board, it should show the money value of the button instantly, since clicking it calls a method that changes the game state. If there's a lot of users on sometimes it takes 4-5 seconds for the money value to show up. I'm guessing it might have to do with my Methods. The game is designed with a Rooms collection which stores all the information about the current game, like state, current clue that the users see, etc. The users' templates are rendered based on the one Room object that they're in. So in my client helpers, there's a bunch of statements like

```
if(Rooms.findOne({_id: Meteor.user().currentRoom}).gameState == 1) {
  .... 
}
```

Is using queries like that in helpers bad and possibly be causing the lag?

My methods have lots of calls to Rooms.update and timeout functions to change the game state. For example:

```
Rooms.update({_id: Meteor.user().currentRoom}, {
    $set: {currentState: 2, ..... }});

Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    Rooms.update({_id: Meteor.user().currentRoom}, {
        $set: {currentState: 3, ..... }});
    }, 3000);
```

I also thought maybe if several users were calling this method then it might be the reason for the lag. I feel like I'm making an obvious really bad decision in the design of the game or there's an obvious problem that I'm not seeing.

Comment: i think using https://kadira.io/ will help you.

Comment: What does `currentState: 3` represent?

Comment: well with a three second timeout, no wonder... what's that for? kadira academy is great for this sort of thing, it will help you defer blocking operations.. https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-performance-101

Comment: Yes, the 3 second timeout is weird. Also in your schema the user can only be in one room at a time (even across multiple logins/devices) which is also odd. Why not just have *currentRoom* be a Session variable? Have you profiled your js code on the client to see where time is being spent?